# Change font size in Google Visualization Motion Chart

Tags: font-size, google-visualization

How can I (if anyhow) control the font size of axis in [Google Visualization Motion Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html)?

In several chart types I can change the text size with property `axisFontSize` bit it does not make effect to Motion Chart.

Comment: If there is I can't find it. There are requests though on the Google Code site requesting this feature.

Comment: @CResults: Can you provide a link to that resource?

Comment: Sure, have a look at this http://tinyurl.com/yksonl2

Comment: @CResults: Thanks. If you post it as as answer, I'm gonna accept it, since so it seems that's not officially supported yet, and that's the correct answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `axisFontSize` isn't supported yet for this chart type.

See the [feature request on the Google Code site](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11&q=font%20size&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).